# How to convert csv files encoding to utf-8

Tags: csv, encoding, utf-8, import, converters

Is it possible to convert csv data that has `iso-8859-13` encoding to `UTF-8`?

My old system does not have `UTF-8` encoding, it uses only `iso-8859-13`. The system that I need to import to does not have `iso-8859-13`, but has both `UTF-8` and `UTF-16`. If I try to open the csv file with an encoding other than `iso-8859-13`, then some symbols are not recognized. If I try to import such file into the new system, it gives an error that I have wrong encoding. I can only import it using `windows-1252`, but then it will import with unrecognized symbols. What can I do to convert it to normal encoding such as `UTF-8`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was able to convert simply using text editor. I opened csv file with `iso-8859-13` encoding. Then created empty csv file with `utf-8`. Then simply copied everything from one csv to another. Then I could import it into new system.

Previously I tried to do this with libreoffice, but for some reason it would save with `iso-8859-13` encoding.

Comment: One side note: This worked as expected but I made a mistake of saving the file to CSV **again**. This totally messed up my file :) One should probably save it to some binary  format (e.g. xlsx) in order to retain changes ;)

Comment: The same process will work in Linux using Kate and/or Kwrite as the editor rather than Notepad or Notepad++ from Windows.

Answer (score 38):

Open the file in Notepad++ and click **Encoding->Convert to UTF-8**.

(Do not click **Encode in UTF-8** because it won't actually convert the characters.)

Comment: made my half-day. the other half I spent searching

Comment: I had to do "Convert to UTF-8-BOM"

Comment: I did first "Convert to UTF-8-BOM" and then "Convert to UTF-8". This saved my umlauts

Answer (score 5):

For those who don't know how to convert the file's encoding using Notepad++ : 
Create a new file in Notepad++ -> Go to Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8 -> Copy-paste the contents -> save the file as .csv

Answer (score 2):

For me worked that way: Open CSV file with regular Notepad. Save as in Notepad and set encoding like in picture.[Encoding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4YOP.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Copying .csv content from Excel to Notepad++ does not preserve format, **open original .csv in Notepad++** and copy from there.

1. Once opened in Notepad++, create new file in Notepad++ using 'Ctrl + n'.
2. Go to Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8-BOM -> Copy-paste the contents -> save the file as .csv.

(Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

I opened my file in MS Notepad, and then the `File > Save As` menu would let me choose the encoding.

[image: Screenshot]