# python/pyspark - Reading special characters from csv and writing it back to the file

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am reading a csv file which has some of the values in a column like this -

```
MÉXICO
ATLÁNTICO
```

I am reading the file with encoding = 'utf8' but after the processing values are getting changed like below

```
Mï¿½XICO
ATLï¿½NTICO
```

What can I do to retain the original value which is in input file.

Edit - Tried utf-16 and ISO-8859-1 also. but does not help either.

Comment: Start with determining the encoding of the input data with `chardet` utility

Answer (score 1):

Your input file may not be in utf8 encoding.
You can convert to utf8 before reading from the file. That should fix your issue.

Here is a stack-overflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693139/how-to-convert-csv-files-encoding-to-utf-8) to convert CSV from non utf8 to utf8 encoding.

Comment: But changing the file manually is not an option for me. I have tried reading the file as utf-8, utf-16, without any explicit option in pyspark but none is retaining the original characters

Answer (score 0):

Use encoding as windows-1252, this will work