# Converting special characters from csv to csv UTF-8

Tags: csv, import, encoding, utf-8, converters

I've just tried converting my "normal" csv (produced by MS Excel when saving an xls just as ordinary csv) into csv UTF-8 using the "Convert to UTF-8" feature of Notepad++ as explained here:
[How to convert csv files encoding to utf-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693139/how-to-convert-csv-files-encoding-to-utf-8)

One problem is that the british pound sign (£), which is originally encoded in my csv as A3, got converted into D088 and so is showing up as "J" now. The following link tells me that it should be C2A3 instead and manually changing D088 to C2A3 fixes it indeed:
http://unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2009-m06/0069.html

Is it a Notepad++ issue by chance? Is there perhaps any other way of converting it properly, so there's no need to fix anything like that afterwards? My MS Excel has no "Save as csv UTF-8" option.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The original was in ISO-8859-1 or Cp-1252 for £ being A3. This is also the Unicode value (as your link shows). Check in Notepad++ that the recognized encoding is ISO-8859-1, and then store it as UTF-8. A manual error seems most likely. Test other special chars.

Comment: @JoopEggen: thanks for your reply. My Notepad++ says it's ANSI in the bottom right... does it mean it's ISO-8859-1?

Comment: Update: I've just tried saving the "very original" xls file as "csv UTF-8" on another PC where Excel does have such option - and apparently the pound sign is just A3 there (single octet). The resulting file is only different by the 3 BOM octets at the very beginning. Just curious now: what makes Notepad++ think it should convert A3 to D088? Is there a way to customize its conversion asking it not to? Or perhaps is there some other tool that can leave it intact during the conversion?...

Comment: ANSI is a nonamer; any single byte encoding would do, but the web thinks Notepad++ means ISO-8859-1 or such. Could be a bug then, of a developer without British keyboard. You could generate all 128 high bit bytes, and check.

Comment: Btw seems like normal Notepad built into Windows also treats my csv exact same if I change encoding from ANSI to UTF-8 when saving it. Interestingly it seems to use UTF-8 for all *new* files created in it, and if I enter the pound sign it's saved as C2A3. I feel there's some theory behind it as it'd be quite surprising to see a similar bug in >1 tool stay concealed for so long but hopefully I'll dig down to the root cause one day.

Comment: Maybe a BOM char at the begin of an "ANSI" file or something esoteric like that.