# How can I convert a csv file using the csv dart package that contains ä, ö, ü, (different charset than US-ASCII)?

Tags: flutter, csv, dart

I am trying to convert a csv file to `List<List>` using the dart package csv, but failed when the file contained characters such as ä or ö which are not part of US-ASCII. I looked into the [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/csv/latest/csv/CsvToListConverter-class.html) and didn't find any setting to change the character set. It only states that the converter follows the rules of rfc4180.

> This converter follows the rules of rfc4180.

On their [webpage](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180) they state:

> Common usage of CSV is US-ASCII, but other character sets defined
> by IANA for the "text" tree may be used in conjunction with the
> "charset" parameter.

This is the error I am getting:

```
Error: FormatException: Missing extension byte (at offset 120)
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:5333:11)
at convert._Utf8Decoder.new.convertGeneral (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:49223:19)
at convert._Utf8Decoder.new.convertSingle (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:49195:19)
at Utf8Decoder.convert (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:49054:67)
at Utf8Codec.decode (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:48760:22)
at asset_bundle.PlatformAssetBundle.new.loadString (http://localhost:55338/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:2308:31)
at loadString.next (<anonymous>)
at http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:39031:33
at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:38888:58)
at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:33874:29)
at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:34434:49)
at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:34472:17)
at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:34314:23)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:34337:35)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:39175:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:39181:13)
at http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:34688:9
```

This is the code

```
  Future<String> determineNewWord({String path}) async {
    final myData = await rootBundle.loadString(path);
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);
    print(csvTable);
    String newWord = csvTable[Random().nextInt(csvTable.length)].first;
    return newWord.toUpperCase();
  }
```

I can't find a place to change the parameter, does this dart package not support other character sets?

Thank You! :)

Comment: What charset is the file in? If you look at the stacktrace you can see it is trying to use UTF-8 (and therefore not US-ASCII) but fails parsing the file so it looks like your file is not UTF-8 compatible.

Comment: @julemand101 You were right, I used the default Excel charset which I think was ANSI, I fixed it by [converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18693139/how-to-convert-csv-files-encoding-to-utf-8) the file to UTF-8. Thank you a lot :), you saved me a lot of time trying to solve an issue that wasn't the actual issue.

Comment: @julemand101 If you want to leave it as an answer I would be more than happy accepting it 

Comment: No problem. I have posted an answer you can accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the exception it seems more likely that it is trying to parse your file using the UTF-8 decoder:

```
...
at convert._Utf8Decoder.new.convertGeneral (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:49223:19)
at convert._Utf8Decoder.new.convertSingle (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:49195:19)
at Utf8Decoder.convert (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:49054:67)
at Utf8Codec.decode (http://localhost:55338/dart_sdk.js:48760:22)
...
```

Please verify that your CSV file is actually saved as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there shouldn't be any problems.

Below is a simple example as proof.

`bin/data.csv`

```dart
German,English
fallen – fällen,to fall – to fell
Fuß – Füße,foot – feet
alt – älter – am ältesten,old – elder – eldest
voll – füllen,full – fill
lang – Länge,long – length
Laus – Läuse,louse – lice
```

`bin/test_csv.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:fast_csv/fast_csv.dart' as _fast_csv;

void main(List<String> args) {
  final source = File('bin/data.csv').readAsStringSync();
  final data = _fast_csv.parse(source);
  print(data.join('\n'));
}
```

Output:

```
[German, English]
[fallen – fällen, to fall – to fell]
[Fuß – Füße, foot – feet]
[alt – älter – am ältesten, old – elder – eldest]
[voll – füllen, full – fill]
[lang – Länge, long – length]
[Laus – Läuse, louse – lice]
```

This is because there are no restrictions on character sets in CSV format.